# scrollview is extremly slow on ics (android 4.0) when containing a long textview

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

Here's my problem, i'm developing a news applicaiton and i used scrollview wrapping a textview to show the content of the news. 
But i found that scrolling is extremly slow on android 4.0 ics when the textview is quite long, and the longer the text, the slower the scrolling is. While on android 2.3 devices things just go as fast as expected.

I don't know whether this is really a system bug cause i found this [similar problems reported on the android project](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22514)

Here's my layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@id/lst_news_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/tv_news_details_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/Detail_Title"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/tv_news_details_category"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/Detail_Category"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/tv_news_details_created_at"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    style="@style/Detail_Time"/>

                <include layout="@layout/detail_horizontal_divideline" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@id/img_news_details_image"
                    style="@style/Detail_Picture"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_contentDescription"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/tv_news_details_context"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    style="@style/Detail_Content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dip" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

     <!-- actionbar shadow -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_shadow"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And my style.xml

```
<style name="Detail_Title">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/list_item_title</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
     <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/list_item_text_shadow</item>
     <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
     <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
     <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
 </style>

 <style name="Detail_Category">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/list_item_category</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
     <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/list_item_text_shadow</item>
     <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
     <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
     <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
 </style>

 <style name="Detail_Time">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/list_item_time</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
     <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/list_item_text_shadow</item>
     <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
     <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
     <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
 </style>

 <style name="Detail_Content">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/detail_content_text</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
     <item name="android:autoLink">all</item>
     <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/list_item_text_shadow</item>
     <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
     <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
     <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
 </style>

 <style name="Detail_Picture">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/image_frame</item>
 </style>
```

By the way, i've already set

`android:minSdkVersion="7"`
`android:targetSdkVersion="14"`

But haven't set the hardware accelerated flag yet.

Is there any solution? Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, i've found the solution on my own

just set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in the manifest.xml

Still quite confused about the reason, waiting for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the fix. I have experience the same issue as with the others. It seems like a bug about this had been opened more than a year ago. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22514

Comment: Unfortunately the "fix" improves scrolling, but doesn't completely solve the problem. It's still laggy/jittery on my Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can add the `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` for a specific activity (or even a specific view) as seen here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html if you want to keep the rest of your app hardware accelerated.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in XML, though. Only programmatically using setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null).